# Implicit move constructor shall be noexcept if possible

Tags: c++, move-constructor, noexcept

Basically per the standard:

> An inheriting constructor (12.9) and an implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) have an *exception-specification*. If `f` is an inheriting constructor or an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, **move constructor**, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit *exception-specification* specifies the type-id `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the *exception-specification*
>   of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` has the *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

Therefore the following code snipped shall have an implicit **noexcept** move constructor:

```
template<typename _Tp>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    explicit Foo(const std::string& s, const std::function<bool(_Tp&)>& f) : stringField(s), funcField(f) {}

private:
    const std::string stringField;
    std::function<bool(_Tp&)> funcField;
};
```

but unfortunately, it does not:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::string: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<std::string> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::function: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<std::function<bool(std::string&)>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string_t: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Foo<std::string>> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
std::string: 1  
std::function: 1  
string_t: 0
```

using g++ 8.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there something I am missing?

Yes. `const`

The member `Foo::stringField` is not `std::string`, it is `const std::string`. `const std::string` is not nothrow move constructible<sup>1</sup>, and therefore the implicit move constructor of `Foo` is neither.

<sup>1</sup> Const rvalue cannot bind to a non-const rvalue reference, so move constructor will not be used. Instead, copy constructor is used and copy constructor of `std::string` is potentially throwing.